# Cross domain webservice - script error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cross-domain

I have a web service hosted in some server. I am trying to access it from my localhost.

I am getting a javascript error :

```
status = 0
responseText = null
```

The same application working fine when hosted in the same server problem only coming when i am accessing it form localhost.

Any suggestion to fic this?

Comment: Code is working fine when both web service and the site calling are in same domain..so for clarity i did not add the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after changing the data format to JSONP form JSON.